# Flipping rows to columns in Bootstrap grid responsively

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Given the following grid layout of buttons:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form class="form" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you run this in a narrow viewport then you get each letter pair of buttons visibly grouped/touching.  If you run it in a wide viewport (click the "full page" button) then you get the numbered triplets touching with the letter pairs separated by a column gap.

I want the lettered buttons visibly together regardless of viewport size.  I tried flipping the layout:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form class="form" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And, unsurprisingly, now things are reversed: the numbers are grouped in a small viewport and the letters are grouped in a large viewport.

Is there a simple way to make the letters appear grouped regardless?  I do still want to have a grid layout in larger viewport sizes though, and I don't want to have to define custom rules/classes for this case.

**Edit**: to try to make this clearer, what I am trying to achieve is:

- In narrow viewports, appear like the first snippet does in a narrow viewport: full-width buttons arranged in three groups of the two same-letter buttons, with vertical separation between each group of two.
- In wide viewports, appear like the second snippet does in a wide viewport: three columns, each containing two same-letter buttons with no vertical separation, only horizontal separation between the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet basically does what I want, but I don't like having to manually override styles.  I was hoping there was something more built-in that does something similar.  (And not just adding custom CSS rules that do the same thing.)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form class="form" role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 12px">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" style="margin-top: 0">Button A2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 12px">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" style="margin-top: 0">Button B2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 12px">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" style="margin-top: 0">Button C2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This one also works, but again needs a custom style:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form class="form" role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 6px">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="width:100%">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 6px">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="width:100%">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 6px">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="width:100%">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <form class="form" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-16">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-16">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-16">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-16">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-16">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-16">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button C2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That just removes the row spacing in the narrow viewport (which I want to keep).  It doesn't affect the wide viewport at all.

Comment: Updated the code. Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: No, now they're just full width regardless of viewport size.  And `col-sm-16` isn't valid in Bootstrap.